# Javascript Date Timezone String unexpected change

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have recently been updated to Chrome  67.0.3396.30 on the beta channel and I have noticed that the new Date().toString() now returns a much longer string (e.g. "British Summer Time" for the timezone which was up till Chrome 66 was returned as a 3 character alphabetic code (e.g. "BST").

Much as I realise that the 3 digit codes are far from unique, they are very handy for displaying the current timezone when the screen real estate is limited as on small devices (i.e. phones), and nearly all users will understand what the timezone code means where there are possible conflicts.

I expect there is no way for us to get the three character codes any longer, so I expect I will have to add a translation table. Can anyone point me in the direction of a full set of possible responses. And a conversion table as well would be just awesome.

In particular I am after an answer in the form of a table of timezone strings and codes and not an external javascript library.

Comment: have you looked at [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to see if you can get it formatted to use the shorter timezone

Comment: Normally I'd say use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) - specifically [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/#the-rfc-2822-date-time-format), but even that has a note on the timezone abbreviations being deprecated - see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-4.3

Comment: @PatrickEvans: Sadly, it doesn't look like `timeZoneName` (which has the tantalizing options `"short"` and `"long"`) is well-supported yet. Chrome doesn't appear to support it, and [Microsoft say they don't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/intl-datetimeformat-object-javascript).

Comment: How about regexing it to pull out the first letter of each word? `'(Eastern Daylight Time)'.match(/\b(\w)/g).join('')` ==>> `'EDT'`

Comment: @jbyrd Needs checking. For example on Firefox you could get `W. Europe Standard Time` which is `WEST` after regexp, but the acronym is `WET`.

Comment: The dup is not an exact dup, but has all the information you need.  In particular, you can see how to get abbreviations out of moment-timezone by following the link in my answer.

Comment: I was really after an answer that does not require any external library code. All I want is a table of data.

Comment: I have found a list at https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/. Can anyone say whether this is what Chrome 67 uses? What about Mobile Safari?

Comment: The names of timezones are not standardised and in some cases the abbreviations are duplicated and triplicated. Also, different implementations give different names and abbreviations and some timezone names are supported by some and not by others, and some aren't supported at all. So just find your own resource (e.g. [*Time Zone Abbreviations – Worldwide List*](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)) and go with that.

Comment: @PatrickEvans—there is no standard for timezone names, the Intl object will likely be as inconsistent as browsers. It's actually pretty useless if a consistent format across browsers is required.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Not sure my question is a duplicate because I was asking for an agreed translation from a long timezone string to a short timezone string, not the other way. I have used the reference I found (above) provided and added @jbyrd's clever little idea as a fallback.

Comment: @SteveBrooker—re @jbyrd's idea: not all implementations use the same name or abbreviation for timezones. Some don't have names for timezones that others do have hames for. And if you abbreviate the timezone as, say, "IST", is that Irish, Indian or Israeli standard time?

Comment: In my example, my users would know whether the coding meant Irish, ,Indian or Israeli based on the context, and anyway I do not have the display space to show more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that there's no such list. Moreover since in ECMAScript specification says that it is implementation-dependent:

> Return an implementation-dependent String value that represents tv as a date and time in the current time zone using a convenient, human-readable form.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-todatestring

or in 2019 version:

> Let tzName be an implementation-defined string that is either the empty string or the string-concatenation of the code unit 0x0020 (SPACE), the code unit 0x0028 (LEFT PARENTHESIS), an implementation-dependent timezone name, and the code unit 0x0029 (RIGHT PARENTHESIS).

https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-timezoneestring

It looks to me that you may want to use some library to have predictable results on all browsers.

Comment: Where is the data source that such a library would use?